# How should I fix this PostgreSQL installation?

Tags: postgresql, installation, psql

I realized that PostgreSQL was already running on my laptop (Mac OS X) before I installed from the Postgres site. So when I used the installer, I got the PostgreSQL and logged in to the postgres user account that was created.

In the terminal I wrote

```
psql -U postgres
```

And provided my password. I got logged in but it said,

> WARNING: psql version 9.0, server version 9.1.
>            Some psql features might not work.

How should I go about fixing this so that I can access the database properly without any issues?

Answer (score 6):

The warning comes from [**psql**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-psql.html), the PostgreSQL interactive terminal. Nothing bad will happen.

As you have two versions of PostgreSQL installed in parallel, you would need two versions of psql. Maybe you even have them on disk. But when you type the command `psql`, your system will default to one of those, not knowing beforehand which database server version you are going to connect to.

You can type the explicit path to the psql version you want. Find the full path of all variants with this shell command (works with Linux, not tested with Mac OS X):

```sh
which -a psql
```

If you did not also install the psql version 9.1 along with your PostgreSQL, you have to install it first, of course.
If you are not going to use PostgreSQL 9.0 any more, you can uninstall it to remove ambiguities.

In Debian you can also set the default of multiple alternatives with:

```sh
update-alternatives
```

But in Debian you also have a wrapper that calls the matching psql dynamically if you specify the database cluster like this:

```sh
psql --cluster 9.1/main
```

Not sure about Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0):

You have installed postgresql-server 9.1 (server side) and postgres (client side 9.0). Maybe you have installed client 9.1 too, but it is not on the path, so you have to find it or if you have not it, then install it.